# Is it correct and natural to say "the video says" meaning that the presenter or people give some information?

Tags: grammar

Is it correct and natural to say *the video says* meaning that the presenter or people give some information? For example:

> **The video says** that it takes one a few years to learn how to play the piano.

If it doen't sound right, would be more natural to say the following?

> In the video **they say** that it takes a few years to learn how to play the piano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both would be considered correct and natural. "To say" can mean both "to express in words" and to "indicate, show" or "communicate" ([link](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/say)). In this case, when you say "The video says..." you are saying that the video has communicated a certain piece of information. In the same way, you might say "The clock says it is five minutes after twelve" or "The directions say to turn the screw clockwise".

Comment: I don't think "the video says" is "natural". And it definitely is not technically correct. Can you quote some examples from reliable sources please.

Comment: *The video says* is quite natural and grammatical. It's no different than "the clock *says* five minutes after twelve" or "a glance that *said* all that was necessary." It's comes from the senses of [*say*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/say) that mean **indicate**, **show**, or **communicate**.

Comment: @AIQ - this is entirely idiomatic for any source of written or recorded instructions: "The cookbook says to add the milk slowly," or "The instructions say that you should turn off the computer first," or "The video says that this plant thrives in indirect sunlight."